# Unable to Host My WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I have written a simple `WCF` code. and want to host it . but when I run it shows me an exception

`HTTP could not register URL http://+:8080/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace`
I have a class library project, in which I have written my `WCF` code. then I added `App.config` file and write some codes

App.config code :

```
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="DEMO1.HelloService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior">
        <endpoint address="HelloService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="DEMO1.IHelloService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="HelloService" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="DEMO1.IHelloService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="Mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080"/>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8090"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

this is my Interface

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IHelloService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetMessage(string name);
    }
```

and i implemented this

```
 public class HelloService : IHelloService
    {
        public string GetMessage(string name)
        {
            return "Name : " + name;
        }
    }
```

then I added another console project to that solution and

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            using(ServiceHost host=new ServiceHost(typeof(DEMO1.HelloService)))
            {
                try
                {
                    host.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("Started");
                }catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

My hierarchy 
[image]

Comment: Can you tell me about your service is run with administrator or not ?

Comment: Have you tried running the application as an administrator on the box?

Comment: @Singh: how can i check it, as WCF code is written in Class Library , When I Write localhost:8080  in browser, then nothing is happing, page says `unable to connect`

Comment: @Lawrence: hey thanks you. it works. I run it in Admin Mode .

Comment: can you change your baseaddress by you ?

Comment: @Lawrence: but I want to see method in browser which I have written in interface , how can I do this ?

Comment: @Singh: yes , I have Changed it to from 8080 to many others like 8030, 8040 and so on...

Comment: It is exactly problem create by you. You can't change it. If you can then you can change only port number not all full address.When i was work on it then i found and i solved it by this method.

Comment: @Singh: I got it . First I run my Console application , then I open That url in my browser, now I can see methods of interface . 
thanks for your kind help .

Comment: I feel good when i help to other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any service which is hosted via HTTP.SYS (which includes WCF) [requires permission to the namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768(v=vs.110).aspx) you are attempting to use (`http://localhost:8080`, in your case).

Either run as administrator, or [add an urlacl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307223(v=vs.85).aspx) which allows your process access to the namespace.

In an administrator command prompt:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/ user=BUILTIN\Users
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem come when you can change manually `baseaddress`. So wcf service doesn't find the service location where service is located so if you can change your service `baseaddress` port then you can change only port number and shouldn't change all address. If you changed all address then address doesn't find service location and service has been giving error.